# KSQL Table which shows last recent non-null value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

At the moment I have a stream with several sensor data, which send their status code once when they update themselves.

This is a one-time value, then the sensor value is zero again until something changes again. So in my table the last value should replace the zero values until a new value is delivered. Currently i create my table like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE LRS WITH 
 (KAFKA_TOPIC='lrs', KEY_FORMAT='DELIMITED', PARTITIONS=6, REPLICAS=3) 
  AS SELECT
  Device,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(CAST(Sensor1 AS DOUBLE)),
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(CAST(Sensor2 AS DOUBLE))
  FROM RELEVANT_VALUES RELEVANT_VALUES
  WINDOW TUMBLING ( SIZE 10 SECONDS ) 
  GROUP BY Device
```

So instead of behaving like this:

```
Device | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Timestamp

  1    |   null  |  null   |   05:00am
  1    |   3     |   2     |   05:01am
  1    |   null  |  null   |   05:02am
  1    |   null  |  null   |   05:03am
  1    |   2     |   1     |   05:04am
  1    |   null  |  null   |   05:05am
```

it should look like this while updating the values:

```
Device | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | window

  1    |   null  |  null   | 05:00-01
  1    |   3     |   2     | 05:01-02
  1    |   3     |   2     | 05:02-03
  1    |   3     |   2     | 05:03-04
  1    |   2     |   1     | 05:04-05
  1    |   2     |   1     | 05:05-06
```

I basically want to create a Table which always show the latest sent value, which is not null.

Is there a way to achieve this using KSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a filter before if you are using streams or with ksql you can do something like `WHERE Sensor1 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: What would give me just the rows at timestamp 05:01 & 05:04am, but thats not my intended result. I want to have Sensor 1 value forwardfilled until the next value arrives.